# Add sub-metas to the data explorer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, data-dump, per-site-meta

Now the sub-metas are included in the data dumps and the data explorer has been updated, shouldn't they be listed on the data explorer as well?

Comment: Its planned, but these data dumps are so tiny I see very little value in it at the moment.